# template function parameter inheritance

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have a dispatcher which can return any type, takes a command, and a FormData object. The idea is that I wish to inherit from FormData when passing around specific stuff.

```
struct FormData {};

struct Form : FormData {};

void login(const Form *f){}

enum Command
{
    LOGIN
};

template <typename T>
T dispatch(const Command command, const FormData *f)
{
    switch (command)
    {
    case LOGIN: login(f);
    }

    return T();
}

int main()
{
    Form f;

    dispatch<void>(LOGIN, &f);

    return 0;
}
```

I get an error saying cannot convert from Form to FormData. I take away the template, everything works fine (but I need the template)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FormData` class is the base class, `Form` is derived, however your *login* function looks like

```
void login(const Form *f){}
```

But in your dispatch function, you are trying to pass a base-class pointer

```
T dispatch(const Command command, const FormData *f)
{
    switch (command)
    {
    case LOGIN: login(f);
    }
```

C++ simply won't let you do that.   Form* can be implicitly converted to a FormData*, but not the other way around.

Perhaps you could add another template parameter to the dispatch function, and let that function figure out the concrete type at compile time:

```
struct FormData {};

struct Form : public FormData {};

void login(const Form *f){}

enum Command
{
    LOGIN
};    

template <typename T>
T dispatch(const Command command)
{
    return T();
}

template <typename T, typename FormDataType>
T dispatch(const Command command, const FormDataType *f)
{
    switch (command)
    {
    case LOGIN: login(f);
    }

    return dispatch(command);
}

int main()
{
    Form f;

    dispatch<void>(LOGIN, &f);
    dispatch<void>(LOGIN);
}
```

Comment: Although for times when there is no return type or form data, just a command, this fails to compile, which I thought sure would:
 `code`dispatcher->dispatch< void, int* >(LOGOUT, 0)

Comment: @rem45acp if there are instances where the dispatch function is used but the `switch(command)` part of the function isn't, then possibly you could split the rest out into a separate specialisation of _dispatch_.  (will update the example..)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert implicitly from `Form*` (derived class) to `FormData*` (base class), but you *cannot* implicitly convert from `FormData*` (base class) to `Form*` (derived class).

Once you enter the `dispatch` function, the compiler knows you have a pointer to the base class `FormData`; it doesn't know that you are passing a pointer to a derived class, `Form`.